# Bootstrap 3 - col-md-2 not rendering..?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the following layout, I have a col-md-2 which doesn't seem to be rendering.  You will see it in the part under "Current Projects".  All of the blocks below that in the various sections are to be centered.  I have a col-md-2, col-md-8, col-md-2 with content in the col-md-8.  Right now they all appear to the left, as if that col-md-2 doesn't exist.

```
<div class="row featureBox">

        <div class="col-md-2"></div>

        <div class="col-md-8"> CONTENT HERE </div>

        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.col-md-offset-2` class with your `col-md-8` div. The code will look like this:

```
<div class="row featureBox">

        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8"> CONTENT HERE </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this works.  The strange thing is I did have the proper whitespace showing in the col-md-2 div, which all of a sudden stopped showing.

Answer (score 2):

If your first `.col-md-2` is empty it's not rendered. If you want it rendered you need to put some content in it, eventually whitespace (not recommended, as it will show up on smaller widths as empty space above the content of your `.col-md-8`).

If the only reason you added that column was to offset the middle column, all you need is

```
<div class="row featureBox">

    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"> CONTENT HERE</div>

</div>
```

Same goes for `xs`, `lg` or `sm`.